# Can I Select Rows After a Row With a Certain Value For Every Partition?

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to detect users first sessions.

| ID | event_server_date | Event | Row_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-26 09:43 | abc | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-10-26 09:45 | cde | 2 |
| 1 | 2022-10-26 09:47 | ykz | 3 |
| 1 | 2022-10-26 09:48 | fun | 4 |
| 1 | 2022-10-26 09:50 | start_event | 5 |
| 1 | 2022-10-26 09:55 | x | 6 |
| 1 | 2022-10-26 09:56 | y | 7 |
| 1 | 2022-10-26 09:56 | z | 8 |
| 2 | 2022-10-26 09:12 | plz | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-10-26 09:15 | rck | 2 |
| 2 | 2022-10-26 09:15 | dsp | 3 |
| 2 | 2022-10-26 09:17 | vnl | 4 |
| 2 | 2022-10-26 09:23 | start_event | 5 |
| 2 | 2022-10-26 09:23 | k | 6 |
| 2 | 2022-10-26 09:26 | l | 7 |

**Desired Output:**

| ID | Timestamp | Event | Row_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-26 09:50 | start_event | 5 |
| 1 | 2022-10-26 09:55 | x | 6 |
| 1 | 2022-10-26 09:56 | y | 7 |
| 1 | 2022-10-26 09:56 | z | 8 |
| 2 | 2022-10-26 09:23 | start_event | 5 |
| 2 | 2022-10-26 09:23 | k | 6 |
| 2 | 2022-10-26 09:26 | l | 7 |

Real timestamp column looks like this:   1970-01-20 06:57:25.583738 UTC
I'm using event based data and my table is quite large.

Is there any way for me pick those desired rows only? And discard all events before start_event in every partition.

I've got this far but I have no idea how to discard unwanted events for every partition.

```
SELECT ID, event_server_date , Event,
row_number() over(partition by ID ORDER BY event_server_date ASC) AS Row_number

FROM `my_table` 

ORDER BY event_server_date ASC
```

Note: I have been using SQL for only two months so I might not know the concepts you're talking about.

Comment: Is there a way to create an expression that returns `true` for desired events and `false` for unwanted events? If so then put it in a `where` clause of a trivial `select` query and you are done. Maybe something like `select * from the_table where not event like 'unwanted_event%'`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `COUNT()` as an analytic function along with a rolling sum:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(CASE WHEN Event = 'start_event' THEN 1 END)
                  OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY event_server_date) cnt,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY makro_id
                                 ORDER BY event_server_date) AS Row_number
    FROM my_table
)

SELECT ID, event_server_date, Event, Row_number
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 0
ORDER BY ID, event_server_date;
```

The count generated above will be one or greater once a row is encountered having `start_event`.  We only retain rows late enough for this condition to be true.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with `LAST_VALUE()` analytic function and `QUALIFY`

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table
QUALIFY LAST_VALUE(IF(event = 'start_event', TRUE, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) 
             OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY event_server_date 
                   ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

You can ignore `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` because it's default window in analytic functions but I like it to leave it for the sake of clarity.